# How to solve: Axios request doesn't work while Postman can?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

***I'm sending a `GET` request using `axios`. What I'm trying to pass to this request is a raw data body (type: Object)***

**Here's the code:**

```
export const getAssignQC = async (
  projectId,
  interviewId,
  userId,
  step,
  status,
  type
) => {

  try {

    return await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://{myIp}/qualitycontrol/checkAssignQC",
      headers:{},
      data: {
        projectID: projectId,
        interviewID: interviewId,
        userID: userId,
        step: step,
        status: status,
        type: type,
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in getting assign qc", error);
  }
};
```

**Here's the result:**

[image]

**Network inspector**

[image]
[image]

**Meanwhile, the request works fine on Postman:**

[image]

**What I've tried**:

- Using FormData and assign to the data property: `data: formData` (the keys, values have been appended)

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: Can you open up the Chrome Network inspector (Next to console, "network" tab), and see what details it shows about the request? Also, is both your server and client running on localhost?

Comment: is there a typo ?
https:{myIp}/qualitycontrol/checkAssignQC should be https://{myIp}/qualitycontrol/checkAssignQC

Comment: agreed with @sonali . there seems to be a typo on your `url`. which would make sense since it's returning a `404` which means the resource or url doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry guys. I've updated the question. The ```url``` didn't have the typo at the beginning. I've added the Network Inspector as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the double slash after 'https':

```
url: "https:{myIp}/qualitycontrol/checkAssignQC",
```

I have also made a working sample, if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-thunder-iprks?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi Viet. Thank you really much for the help. The typo here is caused by me. The ```url``` still have ```//``` but I forgot to put that in the code. 
I've checked your nice demo. I'll look at it in more detail